# What is the “↩” keyboard symbol on a Mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard

On a Mac keyboard, what does the symbol on the <kbd>↩</kbd> key mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the difference:

- <kbd>↩</kbd> is the "return" key symbol (default)
- <kbd>⌤</kbd> is the "enter" key symbol (alternative)

Both behave differently but are accessible through the same physical key. Historically, the return key would map to a carriage return, whereas the enter key would map to a newline. Not all applications have to keep this behavior though.

So, on a small Apple Mac keyboard, the same key can perform different functions, although by default the key sends a return—I believe you have to press <kbd>fn</kbd> to have it function as an enter key.

On a large Mac keyboard, there are separate keys for both, actually (as can be seen in the image below). The same applies to Windows keyboards, which have the enter key on the numpad.

[image]

Comment: On Windows machines, there's Return/Enter (return symbol and enter name/label), as well as *Enter* on the numpad. The latter sometimes has a different behavior, e.g. in Excel AFAIK, similar to Enter on OS X. Please also note that full-size Apple keyboard contain *Enter* on the numpad.

Comment: Shift+return isn't normally enter, but fn+return is.